# List of figures in latex document

Tags: floats, code, program

every time i run my  program the list of figures doesn't show so i need to know where the problem is , can someone help me please ?thank you
here's my program :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
%---------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphics}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{openbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido,pst-plot}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{openbib}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.ps.gz}{.eps}{.ps.bb}{'gunzip -c #1}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps.gz}{.eps}{.eps.bb}{'gunzip -c #1}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphics}
\usepackage{curves}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\topmargin=-2cm\headheight=1cm\headsep=1cm\topskip=0cm\textheight=24cm\footskip=1.3cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm\marginparsep=0cm\textwidth=16cm\evensidemargin=0.5cm
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\def\R{\mbox{I\hspace{-0.15em}R}}
\def\N{\mbox{I\hspace{-.15em}N}}
\newcommand{\partiel}{\partial\hspace{0.1ex}}
%-----------------------------------------------
\parsep=1cm
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------
%\include{Page_de_garde}
%-----------------------------------------------
\include{Dédicaces}
%-----------------------------------------------
\include{Remerciements}
%-----------------------------------------------
\baselineskip=16pt
\pagenumbering{roman} % roman 
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{\small{\itshape Table des mati\`{e}res}}
\tableofcontents 
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Liste_des_Figures}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Nomenclature}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Introduction}                           
%---------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\small \chaptername\,\thechapter} \chead{}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Chapitre_1_Modélisation_MAS}            
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Chapitre_2_ifoc}                         
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Chapitre_3_Commande_adaptative}   
%---------------------------------------------------------     
\include{Chapitre_4_hyp}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Chapitre_5_lyap}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\include{Conclusion}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\appendix
%\include{Annexe}
%\emph{}
\include{AnnexA}
%\include{AnnexB}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
%\include{Resumé}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%-------
```

Comment: Use `\listoffigures` instead of  `\include{Liste_des_Figures}`

Comment: thank you so much , it worked

Comment: `\usepackage{epsfig}` no document written after 1994 should be using that, also you should remove the two `\DeclareGraphicsRule` as dvips does not all shell commands via teh quote special any more (for over 10 years)